# sales that affect other product inventory? How can I accomplish this? Help please!

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, inventory, grouped-products, quantity

I apologize if this has been asked already. I also posted this in the magento forums, and am trying to figure out how this can work. I am using the latest version. Here’s my scenario. I have configurable products available in three different package quantities.

50-pack 
5-pack 
single

Here’s the behavior I am after.

Let’s assume that I have 2x 50 packs in stock. I want the inventory to look like this:

50-pack: 2

5-pack: 20

single: 100

Assuming that a single is sold, inventory would look like this:

50-pack: 1

5-pack: 19

single: 99

Assuming that a 5-pack is sold, it would look like this:

50-pack: 1

5-pack: 19

single: 95

and if a 50-pack was sold, it would be:

50-pack: 1

5-pack: 10

single: 50

lastly, if a quantity of 12 was sold it would look like:

50-pack: 1

5-pack: 17

single: 88

Please let me know how I can clarify.

What’s the best approach to achieve this? whether built-in or through an extension, doesn’t matter. I apologize if this has been covered already. I’m not exactly sure on what to search for. I’ve looked at grouped products, and I’m not sure that will meet my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach could be to set this up using Bundle products instead of Configurable. You could have following products then:

- single (simple product)
- 50-pack (bundle product with "single" added as option with qty of 50)
- 5-pack (bundle product with "single" added as option with qty of 5)

This way Magento would handle stock properly. For example if there are 19 "single" items in stock, you should be able to add to cart 3 pieces of "5-pack", 4 pieces of "single" and nothing more.

However, Magento may still display these products in frontend as "In Stock" and validate stock levels at the time of adding product to cart.